# ROS Answers SE migration: corobot urdf

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there the possibility to simulate the corobot in gazebo?
Where can I find the corresponding urdf file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1150/corobot-urdf/) by [camilla](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/150/camilla/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-01-31**:
Try it: http://www.ros.org/cgi-bin/mt-4.3/mt-search.cgi?IncludeBlogs=1&tag=CoroBot&limit=20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think you'll have to make the URDF yourself. The link pointed to by Daniel Vaz is only for ROS control of a real corobot.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/150/camilla/) on 2013-02-01**:
I have seen that there is a model in MRDS but i don't now where to find it